# Get table name from second database in sqlite using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to get the table names of two databases using python. I am getting the tables from first db but not from second db. There is only one table in each database.

Code -

```
import sqlite3

db1 = r"C:\Users\X\Documents\sqlitedb\A.db"
db2 = r"C:\Users\X\Documents\sqlitedb\B.db"


conn = sqlite3.connect(db1)
conn.execute("ATTACH '{}' AS db2".format(db2))

res = conn.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
for name in res:
    tblname = name[0]
    print(name[0])


res1 = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM main."""+tblname+"""
                       WHERE IDKey NOT IN
                         (SELECT IDKey FROM db2."""+tblname+""")
                    """).fetchall()
res2 = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM db2."""+tblname+"""
                       WHERE IDKey NOT IN
                         (SELECT IDKey FROM main."""+tblname+""")
                    """).fetchall()
```

It prints the table from db1 but not from db2.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should repeat the query for the second database:

```
res2 = conn.execute("SELECT name FROM db2.sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
for name in res2:
    tblname = name[0]
    print(name[0])
```

or union the two :

```
res = conn.execute("""
SELECT name from sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
UNION 
SELECT name FROM db2.sqlite_master WHERE type='table' 
""")
```

(Note that if the tablename is different in the two database, your following code will need a fix, because `tblname` is defined inside the loop and it *remembers* only the last value)

Comment: Many thanks. It worked. I might need to change this a bit.